# The azure.microsoft.com domain is blocked for Google Chrome

Tags: azure, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, http-status-code-403

I haven't been able to use any site from https://azure.microsoft.com/ on my Chrome browser for some time. Everything works fine on Edge and Firefox. I don't use VPN or Chrome extensions like Adblock. On chrome I get a message like below:

> The request is blocked.
> Ref A: 6EC268978EAE456FB75BAF9CB28FE4E6 Ref B: WAW01EDGE0310 Ref C: 2021-01-15T19:35:05Z

[image]

In Chrome console:

[image]

Do you know the cause or solution of this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting cookies for azure.microsoft.com resolved the issue.

Instructions are here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdelete-cookies-from-a-site

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't find the site in the google cookies setting, you can try deleting cookies inside the chrome developer tools.

step 1: Open the Chrome developer tools

and press ctrl+shift+I or F12.

[image]

step 2: click on the double arrow and open the application tab

[image]

step 3: find the Cookies tab in the storage section, choose one you wish to clear, and right-click and clear it.

[image]